# Looking for help: SQL Server query about group by in 2 tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables

MEN

```
Fname | City
------------
A     | AA
B     | BB
C     | AA
D     | AA
E     | CC
```

Citys

```
City
----
AA
BB
CC
DD
EE
FF
```

I need a query that will count how many occurrences there are of each type, in each city (include city that not is in the main list)

something like

```
City | Count
------------
AA   | 3
BB   | 1
CC   | 1
DD   | 0
EE   | 0
FF   | 0
```

### Heading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a right join;

```
select 
    cities.city,
    count(men.city)
from
    men 
    right join cities on cities.city=men.city
group by cities.city
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to select all the columns in the city table then you will have to use right join. If you need to select all the columns in the Men table then use left join.

```
Select c.City, count(m.city)
From Men m
Right Join City c ON c.city = m.city
GroupBy c.city
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select C.City,
       count(M.Fname) as [Count]
from Citys as C
  left outer join MEN as M
    on C.City = M.City
group by C.City
order by C.City
```